# initialize amp-list with amp-bind or amp-state at load time

Tags: express, ejs, amp-html

we are using express + EJS engine.
I want to initialize my amp-list with EJS variable containing amp-list items using amp-state and amp-bind.
After search i realized that: amp-bind expressions are not evaluated on page load. but i need it.
How could i have a amp-list with initialized items and infinite load more functionality?

```html
<amp-state id="localState">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "items": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 2}]
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>
<amp-list src="amp-state:localState">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <li>{{id}}</li>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

this list does not have any item at load time.

Comment: hi, do you have any update on this issue to load localstate data on page load

Comment: I needed SSR functionality for SEO and for that i added `for` loop above of the amp-list, But the main question is open.